# Resource for $L^p$ regularity

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations

The $L^p$ theory for elliptic PDE tells us:

If u is a weak solution of $-\Delta u=f$, then we have $\| u\|_{W^{2,p}}\leq C(\|f\|_{L^p}+\|u\|_{L^{p}})$ for $1<p<\infty$.

Any recommandations of resources or books on this kind of results?

Thanks for anyone who could offer help.

Comment: I think your question could be improved if you reveal also the domain and the type of boundary values you are considering. The reference to Gilbarg&Trudinger in the answer below is good if you are considering a bounded domain with homogeneous Dirchlet boundary data. For more general boundary values you have to look elsewhere.

Comment: It should also be noted that the estimate is incorrect in unbounded domains.

Comment: Is there any standard reference for possible adaptations to unbounded domains? I am looking for a way to prove that solutions of $(-\Delta+|x|^2)u=f$ in $R^n$ belong to $H^{s+2}$ if $f$ belongs to $H^s$.

Answer (score 2):

The standard reference is Gilbarg and Trudinger's "Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order", Chapter 9. Caffarelli and Cabre deal with the nonlinear version of the theory in "Fully Nonlinear Elliptic Equations" and it's a nice reference since it provides a different approach from "singular integral" view presented in Gilbarg/Trudinger. Finally, I recommend the exercises in Mooney's notes

**[https://www.math.uci.edu/~mooneycr/EllipticPDE_BasicTheory.pdf](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Emooneycr/EllipticPDE_BasicTheory.pdf)**

once you read the material, they will help you gain insight.

Hope it helps.